# cannot read property of undefined multer

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm making a user login/registration for learning node js express. But I'm having problems with the file uploading because when im submitting a form the console says that cannot read property 'profileimage' of undefined.

I think the problem is that I'm not using properly the multer module, but as i said I'm just a newbie with node.

I really appreciate your help, here is the code

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var expressValidator=require('express-validator');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session=require('express-session');
var passport=require('passport');
var localStrategy=require('passport-local').strategy;
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer=require('multer');
var flash =require('connect-flash');
var mongo= require('mongodb');
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var db=mongoose.connection;
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

//Handle file uploads
app.use(upload.single('file'));

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

//handle epress session
app.use(session({
  secret:'secret',
  saveUninitialized:true,
  resave:true

}));
//passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

//validator
app.use(expressValidator({
  errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value) {
      var namespace = param.split('.')
      , root    = namespace.shift()
      , formParam = root;

    while(namespace.length) {
      formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
    }
    return {
      param : formParam,
      msg   : msg,
      value : value
    };
  }
}));

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(flash());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.messages = require('express-messages')(req, res);
  next();
});
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

this is the code that uses multer, the problem is in the `if(req.file.profileimage)` condition

```
router.post('/register',function(req,res,next){
//recuperar datos del formulario
    var name        = req.body.name;
    var email       = req.body.email;
    var username    =req.body.username;
    var password    =req.body.password;
    var password2   =req.body.password2;

//revisar input de imagen
if(req.file.profileimage){

        console.log('Uploading File..');
        var profileimageOriginalName    =req.files.profileimage.originalname;
        var profileImageName            =req.files.profileimage.name;
        var profileImageMime            =req.files.profileimage.mimeType;
        var profileImagePath            =req.files.profileimage.path;
        var profileImageExt             =req.files.profileimage.extension;
        var profileImageSize            =req.files.profileimage.size;

    }else{
    //set defaut
    var profileImageName='noimage.png';

    }

    //validacion forma
    req.checkBody('name','Name field is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email','Email field is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email','mail not valid').isEmail();
    req.checkBody('username','Userame field is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password','Password field is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password2','Passwords dont match').equals(req.body.passowrd);
    //revisando errores
    var errors= req.validationErrors();

    if(errors){
        res.render('register',{
            errors:errors,
            name:name,
            email:email,
            username:username,
            password:password,
            password2:password2
        });
    }else{//cuando los datos son válidos
        var newUser= new User({
            errors:errors,
            name:mame,
            email:email,
            username:username,
            password:password,
            profileimage:profileImageName
        });
        User.createUser(newUser,function(err,user){

            if(err) throw err;
            console.log(user);
        });

        req.flash('success','your are redy');
        res.location('/');
        res.redirect('/');
    }
});
```

and this is the jade form

```
form(method='post',action='/users/register',enctype='multipart/form-data')
    .form-group
        label Name
        input.form-control(name='name', type='text',placeholder='Enter Name')
    .form-group
        label Email
        input.form-control(name='email', type='email',placeholder='Enter Email')
    .form-group
        label Username
        input.form-control(name='username', type='text',placeholder='Username')
    .form-group
        label Password
        input.form-control(name='password', type='password',placeholder='Enter Password')
    .form-group
        label Confirm Password
        input.form-control(name='password2', type='password',placeholder='Confirm Password')
    .form-group
        label Profile Image
        input.form-control(name='profileimage', type='file')
    input.btn.btn-default(name='submit', type='submit',value='Register')
```

As I said Im sure that the problem is the multer, but I don't know how to fix it, because the name attributes in jade file and users.js are the same. I also checked Multer documentation but I couldn't fix it by myself.

Thx for your help :)

Comment: The issue is that file is undefined on your request obj (req.file in your code).  Any idea why that may be the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `upload.single()`, you only use `req.file` instead of `req.file.profileimage` since the input field name (`profileimage`) is already known (it was passed to `upload.single()`). This means you'll also need to either change your file field `name` attribute from `profileimage` to `file` or change the name passed to `upload.single()`.

I should also add that multer middleware are typically added at the route handler level because the field names typically vary. So to parse the request in this way, you'd remove `app.use(upload.single('file'))` and change your route handler line from:

```
router.post('/register',function(req,res,next){
```

to:

```
router.post('/register', upload.single('profileimage'), function(req,res,next){
```

Comment: Thank you a lot :D, i had to read it 4 times but i understood everything. I really appreciate your help :) I was hitting the wall with my head.